# Why does bootstrap table stack DIVs when adding padding

Tags: bootstrap-4

So when reading about controlling the number of columns in a DIV I must ensure the number of columns adds up to 12.  In the following example I want two columns so I specify each DIV has having `col-6`.  This works correctly, but when I add any type of margin such as `m-2`, it stacks each DIV on top of each other when there is obviously room on the row.

I'm a newb to bootstrap so can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong?  I was expecting two columns with each column having two DIV sections.  I just want the equivalent of cell spacing between however many DIV section are listed under the DIV row.

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 m-2 p-2">
            <h4>Div 1</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 m-2 p-2">
            <h4>Div 2</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 m-2 p-2">
            <h4>Div 3</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 m-2 p-2">
            <h4>Div 4</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Update: It seems as though you should not specify the number of column you want in the same DIV tag as where you specify the spacing.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="m-2 p-2"><h4>Div 1</h4></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="m-2 p-2"><h4>Div 2</h4></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="m-2 p-2"><h4>Div 3</h4></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="m-2 p-2"><h4>Div 4</h4></div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`col` and `row` have margin and padding.

If you add more of them it will break the flow. You should add your margins/paddings into your `div` inside the `col`, not at the same level of the `col`.

Please find attached a short snippet of what i'm trying to explain :

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6" style="background:green;">
        <h2 class="text-center">col A</h2>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6">
            <div class="m-2 p-2" style="background:red;">col AA</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6">
            <div class="m-2 p-2" style="background:yellow;">col AB</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6" style="background:blue;">
      <h2 class="text-center">col B</h2>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6">
            <div class="m-2 p-2" style="background:cyan;">col BA</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6">
            <div class="m-2 p-2" style="background:orange;">col BB</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you are saying.  If you run your code snippet, DIV 1 and DIV2 have no margin around them (no white spacing between the two DIV tags on same row).  DIV 3 and DIV 4 have margins around them but then they stack on top of each other as I describe in the post.  I just want two columns with two DIV in each column where each DIV has some margin around it.

Comment: True. `div 3` & `div 4` are just here to let you see the diff. I'll update my snippet for what you're asking for.

Comment: Edited, let me know if it's what you're looking for @Geekn

Comment: Oh I think I see.  It doesn't seem possible to have spacing between col A and col B without adding more DIVs.  That's why you created sub DIV sections inside of them?  Wouldn't the downside to that approach be that adding more items always makes you choose which column DIV to put them in (either col A or col B), whereas just listing DIV tags with col-6 will allow the page to stack them equally in two columns.

Comment: no, you can use `offset` if you want to have a bigger space without adding margins or paddings. Please check the [offset doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns).
You can also adjust the flow with the breakpoints like `offset-md-1` for example

Comment: @Geekn the idea is that Bootstrap already has its calculations implemented in its classes to accommodate columns inside a row; if you want to have "space" between items you should apply it to the content *inside* the columns, not to the columns themselves

Comment: As said above, you can use `offset` for the columns. 
You can also remove the padding of a column with `no-gutters`.

Comment: Seems like I should just be able to add the equivalent of cell padding in a table cell to have space between each cell of a row, but it doesn't seem to be that simple with a DIV row unless I'm just missing something.

Comment: Are you able to quick draw something to explain it with a mockup ? I'll be able to help you then.

Comment: Also regarding the `no-gutters` class Bootstrap recommends using it along negative margin utilities as well: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#gutters

Comment: My original code is supposed to have the benefit of stacking however many div columns I have inside my row in across two columns.  I like this approach over the old table/row/cell because I can just list them and it will create as many rows as are needed in two columns.  The only missing piece is the equivalent of cell spacing.  When I add cell spacing to the col (m-2), it stacks them which is the issue. Does that make sense?  Maybe m-2 is the not the equivalent of cell spacing in a table.

Comment: check the [nesting](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#nesting)

Comment: I played with it a bit and I think I see.  The padding P-2 cannot be specified in the same div as the COL-6.  This is why you had additional tags.  Thank you.  I've updated the question to reflect this as well.

Comment: Glad to hear. Enjoy Bootstrap ;)